# Product of simple groups has no proper characteristic subgroups?

Tags: group-theory

Let S be a simple group and set $G = S \times ... \times S$. I believe that G has no proper characteristic subgroups but I have no idea about how to prove this. Any help or counterexamples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If *S* is non-abelian then first classify the normal subgroups *G*.  This is very easy and follows from the coordinate-wise definition of conjugation.  Now observe that clearly none of these normal subgroups is characteristic by exhibiting an automorphism moving them.

If *S* is abelian, then this is just linear algebra: every subgroup of the same order is conjugate under an automorphism.